# <ul> tags are not allowed as child tags of <h6> tags?

Tags: html

In my HTML code, there is a code like :

```
<h6>
   <ul>
       <li><!-- Some text--></li>
       <li><!-- Some text--></li>
       <li><!-- Some text--></li>
       <li><!-- Some text--></li>
       <li><!-- Some text--></li>
   </ul>
</h6>
```

For above code I'm getting errors for `<ul>` tag as :

> Element ul is not allowed here

So why I can't place a `<ul>` as a child tag of `<h6>` tag and what's the alternative??

Comment: Why would you do that? Just style ul and li in CSS

Comment: Headings (`<h1>`, `<h2>`...) are for titles or subtitles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of valid HTML structure, the `<h1>`-`<h6>` section heading elements permitted content is [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content), which doesn't include the unordered list `<ul>` element.

Unordered lists are considered to be [flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#flow_content). Therefore the invalid HTML error being thrown "Element ul is not allowed here". To make your HTML structure valid, you could nest each heading element inside a `<li>` since list elements permitted content is flow content.

```html
<ul>
   <li><h6>One</h6></li>
   <li><h6>Two</h6></li>
   <li><h6>Three</h6></li>
   <li><h6>Four</h6></li>
   <li><h6>Five</h6></li>
</ul>
```

Although the above is valid HTML, you also have the option to just use list elements without nested heading elements and simply increase their `font-size` or `font-weight` with CSS to mimic a `<h6>`.

```css
.demo li {
 /* mock default <h6> user agent styles */
  font-size: 0.67em;
  margin-top: 2.33em;
  margin-bottom: 2.33em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul class="demo">
 <li>One</li>
 <li>Two</li>
 <li>Three</li>
 <li>Four</li>
 <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried putting an `<h6>` tag as a child of each list item?

```
  <ul>
    <li><h6>some text</h6></li>
    <li><h6>some text</h6></li>
    <li><h6>some text</h6></li>
    <li><h6>some text</h6></li>
    <li><h6>some text</h6></li>
  </ul>
```

hopefully this helps

Answer (score 2):

The error is thrown because your structure is invalid.

Alternative:

```
<ul>
    <li><h6><!-- Some Text --></h6></li>
    <li><h6><!-- Some Text --></h6></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [html spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements), the content of `h1`-`h6` elements may only be "phrasing content", which does not include `ul` elements ([source](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content-2)).

There are multiple solutions to your problem:

```html
 <ul>
    <li><h6>some text</h6></li>
    <li><h6>some text</h6></li>
    <li><h6>some text</h6></li>
    <li><h6>some text</h6></li>
    <li><h6>some text</h6></li>
 </ul>
```

...or:

```css
ul li {
  display: block;
  font-size: .67em;
  margin-top: 2.33em;
  margin-bottom: 2.33em;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>Some text</li>
   <li>Some text</li>
   <li>Some text</li>
   <li>Some text</li>
   <li>Some text</li>
   <li>Some text</li>
</ul>
```

You could put any CSS you want, really, I just took what most [browsers default to](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp).

The main difference between the answers is that the first solution contains semantic meaning. Considering a list of headings *probably* shouldn't have any semantics, I suggest using the 2nd solution.